# Make a mysql query to multilevel marketing

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to create a select to list a tree in HTML in a multilevel marketing system. My relationship table have:

Members_relations:

```
memberID parentID  
1        2  
1        3  
1        4  
5        NULL  
6        NULL  
7        8  
4        7
```

Members_sales:

```
Id   Sale  
1    500   
2    300  
3    400  
4    150  
5    200  
6    0  
7    0  
8    0
```

For example if I need retrieve the quantity of members above the memberID 1, and i need retrieve in other select for every member above member 1 i need to make another select to take the amount of sales about everyone above member 1, to can make a commission payment for member 1 for example.

How can i make this query? Remember this is a multilevel marketing system,

Comment: Can you show what your desired end result would look like?

Comment: for example, the member 1 have the members 2,3,4 in the first line above, but the member 4 have one member id 7 above him, them firstly i need know how many members have the member 1 ( in this case have 4, 3 directly and 1 in second level), and i need to know the amount of total sales from members above the member 1 ( in this case: member 2=300, 3=400, 4=150 and 7=0, the member 1 have 5% from 850(2+3+4+7))

Comment: Not too fond of your commas in your first few blocks. You don't actually have id's stored as comma-separated lists do you? Also shouldn't a member have only 1 upline parent?

Comment: sorry i dont have the commas into the table, only ids, the commas was an typping error.

Comment: So a parent is like a mentor and a member can have plenty of them?

Comment: yes, think about this system like a pyramid

Comment: Sadly I have been involved in a few :) I will hack something together to show you. Hopefully you will get a few responses

Comment: sorry for your bad experience, but this is a sales pyramid, and i need this query, you can make?

Comment: Yes. but want to make sure you know this is an `inverted pyramid` with a child having multiple uplines as opposed to a typical mlm pyramid. With focus on downlines

Comment: Most of the time in mlm a new lazy recruit doesn't benefit from active productive uplines

Comment: yes, i need a downline pyramid

Comment: Thought so. So you need to revamp basically the whole question

Comment: sorry, the problem is my bad english, but basically i need take one member and run entire table looking for downlines members and take the ammount sales of that members

Comment: @DrewPierce, I also don't understand `inverted pyramid`. Solution posted with a regular tree ... op will match to they requirements (I hope).

Comment: @danihp, the OP 2nd language problem i take it. Wherever he said parent and above he meant child and below. So imagine an upside down pyramid. Even the Egyptians would struggle with that one

Comment: @DrewPierce, lol. Sure, this is an Egyptian issue.

Comment: i want to work in an inverted pyramid and be the last lazy guy in

Answer (score 0):

Here a sample solution. I have changed your tree structure to make more sense to answer. Be free to match the code to exact requirements ( sechema, commisions, ... ) on your environment.

```
Members_relations
parentID memberID    <--- OP, be carefull here
1        2  
1        3  
1        4  
7        8  
4        7
10       100 

Members_sales:
Id   Sale  
1    500   
2    300  
3    400  
4    150  
5    200  
6    0  
7    0  
8    0  
10   999
100  888
```

To figure out it, self joining while children found:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS letsgo;
CREATE PROCEDURE letsgo ( IN id int ) BEGIN
 DECLARE nR INT;
 DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS children;
 CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE children AS (SELECT id as Id);
 DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS children_prev;
 CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE children_prev AS (SELECT id as Id );
 SET nR = ( SELECT count(*) FROM children ); 
 WHILE ( nR > 0 ) DO
   DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS children_aux;
   CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE children_aux AS (
     SELECT memberID as id 
       FROM Members_relations R  
       INNER JOIN  children_prev C on C.id = R.parentID
   );
   SET nR = ( SELECT count(*) FROM children_aux );  
   INSERT INTO children 
      SELECT * FROM children_aux;
   TRUNCATE TABLE children_prev;
   INSERT INTO children_prev
      SELECT * FROM children_aux;   
 END WHILE;
 SELECT SUM( Sale ) 
   FROM Members_sales S 
  INNER JOIN children C on C.id = S.Id;

END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

**Testing:**

```
mysql> call letsgo(1);
+-------------+
| SUM( Sale ) |
+-------------+
|        1350 |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.16 sec)

mysql> call letsgo(100);
+-------------+
| SUM( Sale ) |
+-------------+
|         888 |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.06 sec)
```

*Notice: my apologies by the dirty solution, but this is MySQL: no CTE, no select on recursion on functions, no DO-WHILE, ...*

*Notice: remember than multilevel marketing plans are not allowed ethically and forbidden by law in a lot of countries.*